# Why does latent dirichlet allocation (LDA) fail when dealing with large and heavy-tailed vocabularies?

Tags: natural-language, dirichlet-distribution, word-embeddings, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm reading the 2019 paper *Topic Modeling in Embedding Spaces* which claims that the *embedded topic model* improves on these limitations of LDA. But why does LDA have these limitations—why does it fail on large vocabs and on heavy-tailed vocabs?